# how to dismissModalViewController by clicking tabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

When i didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my tableView, my DetailView is loaded. In detailView i can return to the tableView with a backButton, which dismisses the detailview.

In My app i have in front a tabBar (tabbarcontroller), everytime. When the detailView is loaded and in case of the backbutton is clicked a tabBarItem, **the detailViewController is not dismissed**.
*That means, that i cant load the detailView again, if i didSelectRowAtIndexPath.*

Can someone help my out with this problem?

Thanks,
brush51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UITabBarDelegate protocol has a method called tabBar:didSelectItem:. You may use this method to detect when an UITabBarItem was selected and then call a method to dismiss the detailViewController.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. i have tried: tabBar didSelectItem: if (item.tag == 1) {NSLog(@"test");} not working. Actually, i am using tabBarController didSelectViewController:. Is here anyway to call a dismiss, when the view is changed?

Comment: Have you set the delegate to the class that implements that method?

Comment: The tabbarcontroller:didSelectViewController is in my AppDelegate. i set the delegate of tabbarcontroller. here: self.tabBarController.delegate = self; Can you tell me, how i can find out from tabbarcontroller:didSelectViewController if detailViewController is loaded or not?